# Value of Fortran DO loop index after the loop

Tags: loops, fortran, do-loops

How do DO loops work exactly?

Let's say you have the following loop:

```
do i=1,10
...code...
end do

write(*,*)I
```

why is the printed I 11, and not 10?

But when the loop stops due to an

```
if(something) exit
```

the I is as expected (for example i=7, exit because some other value reached it's limit).

Comment: Sorry, but didn't found that question. Mine is a duplicate. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: See also sections 8.1.6.6.2 ans 8.1.6.6.4 of the [Fortran 2008 standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf). The latter states: "When a DO construct becomes inactive, the DO variable, if any, of the DO construct retains its last defined value.", while the former gives details on loop iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `i` goes to `11` before the `do` loop determines that it must terminate. The value of `11` is the first value of `i` which causes the end condition of `1`..`10` to fail. So when the loop is done, the value of `i` is `11`.

Put into pseudo-code form:

```
1) i <- 1
2) if i > 10 goto 6
3) ...code...
4) i <- i + 1
5) goto 2
6) print i
```

When it gets to step 6, the value of `i` is `11`. When you put in your `if` statement, it becomes:

```
1) i <- 1
2) if i > 10 goto 7
3) ...code...
4) if i = 7 goto 7
5) i <- i + 1
6) goto 2
7) print i
```

So clearly `i` will be `7` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I always had trouble with the loop variable, hence i reuse it later as a loop bound.

Answer (score 1):

I want to emphasize that it is **an iteration count** that controls the number of times the range of the loop is executed. Please refer to Page 98-99 ["Fortran 90 ISO/IEC 1539 : 1991 (E)"](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N001-N1100/N692.pdf) for more details.

The following steps are performed in sequence:

1. **Loop initiation**:

   1.1 if *loop-control* is

   ```
       [ , ] do-variable = scalar-numeric-expr1 , scalar-numeric-expr2 [ , scalar-numeric-expr3 ]
   ```

   1.1.1 The initial parameter **m1**, the terminal parameter **m2**, and the incrementation parameter **m3** are established by evaluating scalar-numeric-expr1, scalar-numeric-expr2, and scalar-numeric-expr3, respectively,

   1.1.2 The do-variable becomes defined with the value of the initial parameter **m1**.

   1.1.3 The **iteration count** is established and is the value of the expression

   ```
       MAX(INT((m2 –m1+m3)/m3),0)
   ```

   1.2 If loop-control is omitted, no iteration count is calculated.

   1.3 At the completion of the execution of the DO statement, the execution cycle begins.

2.The **execution cycle**. The **execution cycle** of a DO construct consists of the following steps performed in sequence repeatedly until
termination:

2.1 The **iteration count**, if any, is tested. If the iteration count is zero, the loop terminates

2.2 If the **iteration count** is nonzero, the range of the loop is executed.

2.3 The **iteration count**, if any, is decremented by one. The DO variable, if any, is incremented by the value of the incrementation parameter m3.