# Fortran 77 Do Loop block clarification

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Both NUM and ARRAY double precision variables, not sure how the if block will execute. When will it stop? What is it actually doing?, If we go to 8, then are we exiting the do loop?

Thanks

```
DO 7 I = 1,28                                                   
IF (NUM - ARRAY(I)) 8,7,7                                    
7 CONTINUE                                                         
I=29                                                             
8 NUM = ARRAY(I) 
....
....
....
....
```

Comment: How would this look like in modern day language, for example C?

Comment: DO loop is from 1-3 lines. When you are in 4th line you are out of DO loop.

Comment: What if I go to line 4 from line 2? when the condition is satisfied? then I am out of the loop? is it safe to call that a 'break' statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously stated the conditional in the loop is an [arithmetic if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11124855/3157076).

We know (and that's explicitly stated in the previous answer here) that if `num` is less than `array(i)` the label `8` is chosen, otherwise label `7` is chosen.  It's also stated in that other answer that these have the effect of exiting the loop or cycling it.  To be precise, I'll continue.

A DO construct has a range.  A nonblock DO construct like the one in the question has range consisting of the statements between and including the `do` statement and the DO termination statement (in this case `7 continue`).  The DO termination statement is a valid target for a jump from within the range of the construct.

When the DO termination statement is jumped to, execution remains within the scope of the construct.  That termination statement is executed (in this case, `continue`, doing nothing) and the loop iteration condition is again tested.  That is, the loop cycles.

From within a DO construct, a jump to a statement outside the range of the construct terminates execution of the construct: like an exit.

This example, then, has the equivalent form using an IF construct (with `go to`s - bear with me)

```
DO 7 I = 1,28
IF (NUM < ARRAY(I)) THEN
  GO TO 8
ELSE
  GO TO 7
END IF
7 CONTINUE
I=29
8 NUM = ARRAY(I)
```

Now, because the statement labelled `7` is a `continue` statement, we can write this as

```
DO 7 I = 1,28
IF (NUM < ARRAY(I)) THEN
  GO TO 8
ELSE
  CYCLE
END IF
7 CONTINUE
I=29
8 NUM = ARRAY(I)
```

That's still pretty ugly (and not just because of all the upper case).  Fortunately, we can make this prettier.  The `i=29` statement will be executed only when the loop terminates without the statement labelled `8` being jumped to.  Now, the loop index `i` has control `I = 1,28` so when the loop terminates naturally the index already [has the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18146622/3157076) `29`.  That assignment does nothing (in modern Fortran) so we can remove it.  Which leaves us with

```
DO 7 I = 1,28
IF (NUM < ARRAY(I)) THEN
  GO TO 8
ELSE
  CYCLE
END IF
7 CONTINUE
8 NUM = ARRAY(I)
```

When we also note that the IF construct is immediately followed by the end of the loop (and so we don't need to explicitly cycle) we have

```
DO 7 I = 1,28
IF (NUM < ARRAY(I)) EXIT
7 CONTINUE
NUM = ARRAY(I)
```

or (more nicely)

```
DO I = 1,28
  IF (NUM < ARRAY(I)) EXIT
END DO
NUM = ARRAY(I)
```

All this example is doing is finding the value of the earliest element in `array(1:28)` which is larger than `num`, or `array(29)` if none is.

Comment: This is why I can't edit tags. I am sure I voted to close as a duplicate (there are several), but if I lose the hammer priviilege, it won't get enough votes in the review queue and the votes will disappear. We need more people with the golden tag badge.

Comment: Have you a good suggestion as to a duplicate target?  I didn't see one (obviously), but I still have a close vote available on this question.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124855/fortran-if-statement-with-numbers-labels-rather-than-another-statement is already a target of two others. I also have a vote now, they get refunded when they are voided.

Comment: But this one is even older https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789946/strange-label-usage?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Agreed that the second one is a possible candidate, but not the first.  To my mind the interaction with the range of the do is the important part.  (I even link to the question about defining the arithmetic if.)  On the second, I think this here is actually the better question in that it explicitly asks about the loop.

Comment: I see. The other question is a nested do loop and no label points outside so it is also somewhat different.

Comment: Thank you for your time you took to answer the question. Very detailed answer always good. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

That is called arithmetic if: `if(a) 1,2,3` . and it means: if `a<0` it goes to 1, if`(a==0)` it goes to 2 and if `(a>0)` it goes to 3.

in your code if( num-array(i)<0 ) it goes to 8 (exit the loop and skip another line), else it goes to 7 (cycle).